# Selenium wait until any element with a given class is visible

Tags: python, selenium, autocomplete

I'm writing some Selenium tests to make sure my autocompletes are working properly, and I need to give a bit of a delay between entering text in the input field and trying to select from the autocomplete. Rather than just using a fixed delay, I'd rather wait until the list appears. I've tried the following:

```
input_element.send_keys("zanzibar c")
WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "pac-container")))
input_element.send_keys(Keys.DOWN)
```

where `pac-container` is the class of the autocomplete's list element.

This works for the first input with an autocomplete, but times out for the rest. I'm guessing this is happening because it is waiting for the first `pac-container` to be visible, whereas I want it to wait for *any* one of the `pac-container`s to be visible.

Is there a way to wait until at least one element with a given class is visible?

Comment: try the following solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338330/wait-for-class-to-exist-before-continuing-with-selenium-in-firefox/37339179#37339179

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for `presence_of_all_elements_located(locator)`

```
class selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_all_elements_located(locator)[source]
```

> An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present
>   on a web page. locator is used to find the element returns the list of
>   WebElements once they are located

Reference : http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html

Comment: This seems to be waiting until the elements exist, which they already do. I need to wait until one is visible.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:  WebDriverWait don't have anything like "wait for one of them to be visible".

There are two ways to find the first visible element.  The simple way would be to select it with JQuery/Javascript:

```
$('.pac-container').not(':hidden').click();
```

The second way is to get a list of elements and iterate through them, checking to see if any of them are visible:

```
for element in driver.find_elements_by_class_name("pac-container"):
    if element.is_displayed():
        element.do_something()
```

Both of these would need to be in an infinite while loop that you break out of once you have found the element.

Comment: Waiting for the last element to be visible won't help me either, as only one element with the class will be visible at a time. I'm not entirely sure how I would achieve the effect I'm looking for by looping through the elements. I'd imagine that would just make it time out at the first before it got to the next iteration...

Comment: @StephenTG I updated my answer to actually answer your question

Comment: Ok, this kinda put me on the right path. I'm using `WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.pac-container:not([style*="display: none"])')))` now, and your first suggestion nudged me towards trying via css

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping for a CSS selector, but I didn't know how it was invisible.  Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Python bindings and the function below allows you to pass in a list of locators to wait for.

Here is an example of two locators and the locator list:

```
no_records_indicator_loc = (By.XPATH, "//*[contains(text(),'No records to display')]")
edit_button_loc =  (By.XPATH, "//*[@value='Edit']")
locators = [Customer.no_records_indicator_loc, Customer.edit_button_loc]
```

Here is how I call the function:

```
wait_for_one_these_elements_to_be_present(locators)
```

Here is the function

```
def wait_for_one_these_elements_to_be_present(locators, total_time_to_sleep=30):
    # will attempt to find each element on the page until either one is
    # found or the time expires
    total_slept = 0
    i_sleep_sec = .5

    while True:
        time.sleep(i_sleep_sec)

        for loc in locators:
            if len(driver.find_elements(*loc)) > 0:
                return
        total_slept += i_sleep_sec
        if total_slept == total_time_to_sleep:
            raise NoSuchElementException
```

Explanation:

If any are found before the time expires, the function returns. If not, it raises a NoSuchElementException. Technically, the time behaves more like an iterator but it's close enough for me.

The list is iterated through. If any item in the list is found on the page, the function breaks and returns. If no locator in the list is found, then, if total time has expired, raise NoSuchElementException. If time remains to continue checking the page. Repeat.