# Wait for class to exist before continuing with selenium in Firefox

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium

I'm trying to make selenium wait until a certain class is able to be found on a page, I've tried several bits of code but nothing is working

Trying the following:

```
while not firefox.find_element_by_css_selector('.but selected'):
    print "test"
    time.sleep(1)
```

Returns

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element

Trying the following:

```
while not firefox.find_element_by_class_name('but selected'):
    print "test"
    time.sleep(1)
```

Returns:

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: The given selector but selected is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement. The following error occurred:
>   InvalidSelectorError: Compound class names not permitted

Any idea what I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Note: The correct answer is the one below using explicit waits.*

See the  following example. This function will wait till your class appears in DOM.

```
import time
...
...
def wait_for_class_to_be_available(browser, total_wait=100):
    try:
        # Give only one class name, if you want to check multiple classes then 'and' will be use in XPATH
        # e.g //*[contains(@class, "class_name") and contains(@class, "second_class_name")]
        elem = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@class, "class_name")]')
    except:
        total_wait -= 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if total_wait > 1: wait_for_class_to_be_available(browser, total_wait)
```

You can also change the xpath to *'//xpath/to/that/element[contains(@class, "class_name")]'*.
Try one of them, whichever is more suitable to you.

Comment: Edited to indicate that this is the wrong answer and users should read below to use explicit waits.

Answer (score 16):

You could try [explicit-waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits). Here is a small example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


def test(url):
    wait_for_element = 30  # wait timeout in seconds
    firefox = webdriver.Firefox()
    firefox.get(url)

    try:
        WebDriverWait(firefox, wait_for_element).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "but selected'")))
    except TimeoutException as e:
        print("Wait Timed out")
        print(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test("http://www.python.org")
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, not the one marked correct.