# Beautifulsoup returns incomplete html

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, flickr

I am reading a book about Python right now. There is a small project for homework:
"Write a program that goes to a photo-sharing site like Flickr or Imgur, searches for a category of photos, and then downloads all the resulting images."
It is suggested to use only webbrowser, requests and bs4 libraries.

I cannot do it for Flickr. I found that the parser cannot go inside the element (div class="interaction-view"). Using "Inspect element" in Chrome I can see that there are a few "div" elements inside it and "a" element. However, when I use bs4 library it cannot see it.

My code like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# To download photos from Flickr

import requests, bs4

search_name = "spam"
website_name = requests.get('https://www.flickr.com/search/?text='
                       + search_name)
website_name.raise_for_status()
parse_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(website_name.text, "html.parser")
elements = parse_obj.select('body #content main .main.search-photos-results \
                .view.photo-list-view.requiredToShowOnServer \
                .view.photo-list-photo-view.requiredToShowOnServer.awake \
                .interaction-view')
print(elements)
```

It only prints:

```
[<div class="interaction-view"></div>, <div class="interaction-view"></div>...]
```

Without any nested elements and I do not understand why...
Thank you!

Comment: can you correct the code block? the first line should be `#!/usr/bin/env python3` and then `Soup.select` should be `parse_obj.select`. This makes is easier for people to reproduce

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that the content of `<div class="interaction-view"></div>` on flickr is only loaded via javascript. You can check that if you view the page source, you'll find: `<div class="interaction-view"></div>` with no content in the div tag.

You need to execute javascript somehow. Since beautifulsoup doesn't offer this, one solution is to use selenium for that. `pip install selenium` and install [`geckodriver`](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) for firefox (on OSX: `brew install geckodriver`). Then change your code to use selenium to load the page:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import requests, bs4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

search_name = "spam"
url = 'https://www.flickr.com/search/?text=%s' % search_name

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)
delay = 3
WebDriverWait(browser, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located(browser.find_element_by_id('...')))

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source, "html.parser")


elements = soup.select('body #content main .main.search-photos-results \
                .view.photo-list-view.requiredToShowOnServer \
                .view.photo-list-photo-view.requiredToShowOnServer.awake \
                .interaction-view')
print(elements)
```

The `WebDriverWait` part is needed so selenium waits with parsing until a certain element is loaded. You need to change `...` to an id you know will be present. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23118146/selenium-wait-until-any-element-with-a-given-class-is-visible) to check how it can be done with classes.

Comment: Interesting, thank you! I found it needs to add pause (for example time.sleep(5)) before creating BeautifulSoup object. Otherwise, I do not get the "filled" list.
Do I understand correctly:
1) when I "inspect element" in browser I run the JavaScript code and can see "filled" div? 
2) When I just press F12 I do not run JavaScript code. As a result, there is no content in the div tag?

Comment: good point. You first need to wait for a certain element to be present, I updated my answer. `sleep` probably works but waits too long if the loading is fast or might fail if the loading is slow, better go the `WebDriverWait` way

Comment: `F12` opens developer console. This is not the same as the html source. What beautifulsoup sees when doing `requests.get` you see when right click->view source. What selenium sees is whatever you do in the developer console (e.g. when you run `$("body #content...")`)

Comment: also, if you're fine with the answer, then please upvote & accept it. This answer took me about 1h to produce, here on SO the payment for this is upvotes & accepts ;-)

Comment: Thank you! Sure ;)